# get array of database info android?

Tags: android, android-database

this is my code for getting data from database,but any things not show.what's wrong about it

```
public String[] GetData() {

    String[] result =new String[]{};
    int counter=0;
    String[] Columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PHONE, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_ADDRESS};

    Cursor cr = myDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, Columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    int ROW_NAME = cr.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int ROW_PHONE = cr.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE);
    int ROW_EMAIL = cr.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL);
    int ROW_ADDRESS = cr.getColumnIndex(KEY_ADDRESS);


    for (cr.moveToFirst(); !cr.isAfterLast(); cr.moveToNext()) {
       result[counter]= cr.getString(ROW_NAME) + " " + cr.getString(ROW_PHONE) + " " + cr.getString(ROW_EMAIL) + " " + cr.getString(ROW_ADDRESS)+"\n";
        counter++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: please help me in this code!!

Comment: it doesn't show anything or it crushes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize result this way:

```
String[] result =new String[cr.getCount()];
```